# executing select statement stored in table column by replacing variable value dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have  simple PL/SQL block with below code

```
declare 
rule1 varchar2(100 char);
begin
for i in (select table_name from all_tables where table_owner='EqEDI') loop
  execute immediate 'select rule_stmt from rulebook ' into rule1 ;
  execute immediate rule1 into result;
  dbms_output.put_line('Result is '||result);
end loop;
end;
```

the rule statement stored in table rulebook is :

```
"'select count(1) from '|| <tablename>"
```

I want this above statement to be executed for all tables present for given owner
but while executing, it does not replace  in query with actual tables.
How can I achieve it with simple PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rulebook` table's contents is kind of *wrong*. Not that you can NOT do it the way you stored `select` statement into it - it is just impractical as you have to remove single quotes, remove `tablename` (as you can't even bind it, but concatenate what cursor returned) ... too much unnecessary jobs to be done.

Also, check `all_tables` and names of its columns - there's no `table_owner`, just `owner`.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to store such a statement:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM rulebook;

RULE_STMT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select count(*) from
```

Fix your PL/SQL script:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     rule1   VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR);
  3     l_str   VARCHAR2 (100);
  4     result  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR i IN (SELECT table_name
  7                 FROM all_tables
  8                WHERE     owner = 'SCOTT'
  9                      AND table_name = 'EMP')
 10     LOOP
 11        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select rule_stmt from rulebook '
 12           INTO rule1;
 13
 14        l_str := rule1 || i.table_name;
 15
 16        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
 17           INTO result;
 18
 19        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Result is ' || result);
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /
Result is 14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```